# Programatically determine the size of an array of strings

Tags: c

Is there a way in C to know how many values are in an array initialized like this?

```
char *string_array[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

Obviously there are three strings in the array but how can I determine the size at run time?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539/3048692

Comment: Something like `sizeof(string_array)/sizeof(char)`?

Comment: This would give you the result sizeof(string_array)/sizeof(string_array[0])

Comment: @PauloBu No, that would be wrong. Use sizeof(string_array)/sizeof(string_array[0])

Comment: Be careful when doing the trick provided in the possible duplicates answer, because it only works with the actual array. Once you pass an array as an argument to a function it decays to a pointer, and the trick will no longer work as the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

Comment: @nos I see that's better but in this case wouldn't they return the same? (Just a doubt)

Comment: @PauloBu no, the array elements are char pointers, not a char. sizeof(string_array)/sizeof(char*) would be correct too.

Comment: @nos Argh, missed that, so silly. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Why would you need this information "at runtime", when it is patently available at compile time already?